# $1435\binom{20000}{10000}*0.515^{10000}*0.485^{10000} \leq 0.01$

Tags: probability, inequality, approximation, estimation

This inequality is part of a larger probability question and must be shown without explicitly calculating it. 
The only hint I have is to use Stirling's Approximation so $1 \leq \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n } \leq e^{1/(12n)}$

Edit: As requested the broader question. Proof that for $n=10000$, $p = 0.485$
$$(1-\binom{2n}{n}p^n(1-p)^n\frac{1-p}{1-2p})^{82} \geq 0.99$$
I used Bernoulli's inequality and found and upper bound for $\frac{1-p}{1-2p}$. Note that the original question said 14400 when it should have been 1435

Comment: Well, this one seems quite tight for elementary pen paper work, maybe you should be giving the larger question instead.

Comment: Shockingly tight: using 14421 instead of 14400 gives > 0.01.  But now it's changed to a much more amenable number.

Answer (score 1):

I will only give a very short answer, because it is probably not relevant to anyone else and the solution is actually quite simple.
Notice that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2n!}{(n!)^2}$ whose lower bound using Stirling's Approximation is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}(\frac{2n}{e})^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n}*e^{1/(24*n)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} 2^{2n}e^{1/(24*n)}$$
From there you can write the whole thing as
$$1-1435 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} (4p(1-p))^n e^{1/(24*n)}$$
After that you got sane numbers and can do basic estimations.